# mySQL Trigger returns error

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to set up a trigger on a table to copy the contents of a row into another table.

I have the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER story_deleted BEFORE DELETE ON stories 
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO stories_backup SET story_id = OLD.story_id;  
  END;
```

This returns the following error though:

`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3`

I can't work out where I'm going wrong with this. Any ideas?

Comment: The code is correct. How are you executing this query, in phpmyadmin?

Comment: As a workaround - try to remove BEGIN and END keywords.

Comment: trying to execute in phpMyAdmin...

Comment: It can be a problem with source objects and delimiters. Try workaround.

Comment: @Devart This returns the following: `1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled`

Comment: Are you trying to update or insert?

Comment: Find ERROR 1419 - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-logging.html

Comment: I think the problem is that I don't have SUPER privileges and I can't get them without speaking to the technical support team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the delimiter

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER story_deleted BEFORE DELETE ON stories  
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO stories_backup SET story_id = OLD.story_id;   
  END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

and as far as your privileges go, run this query

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

If SUPER is not there, you could

- request your DBA to add that privilege for you
- have your DBA create the trigger for you